# Django/Python: How do i transfer a class's attributes to another via a for loop? (Form->Model Instance)

Tags: python, django

I wish to update a model instance from a form I have.

The form is a ModelForm, so it has the same attributes as the model instance, how do I transfer the attributes from the form instance to the model instance instead of doing this:

modelinstance.name = form.name
.
.
.
.

A for loop perhaps? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Call the save() method of the form.
Specifically instantiate the form with keyword argument `instance` like this:

```
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ArticleForm(instance=a)
>>> f.save()
```

Taken from here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method